# C# - XML retorno de WebService com erro de codificação (ISO-8859-1)

Tags: c#, web-service, codificação-de-caracteres, iso-8859-1

Tenho uma aplicação Windows Forms que está consumindo um WebService que retorna um xml (string) com o enconding ISO-8859-1.

Contudo, a resposta vem com caracteres de interrogação (?) no lugar dos acentos.

Como fazer para converter ou fazer a leitura em ISO-8859-1, para que a acentuação venha corretamente?

Código:

```
        string empresa = "loginEmpresa";
        string token = "tZTMMnOO+oZZmlwhSRuFbQ=="; 
        string xmlPublicacoes = "";

        br.com.dominio.portal.IIFServiceservice webService = new br.com.dominio.portal.IIFServiceservice();

        xmlPublicacoes = webService.ObterPublicacoesPorGrupo(empresa, token, 3997, "01/12/2015");

        MessageBox.Show(xmlPublicacoes); //Aqui o texto com erro de encoding
```

XML Retorno:

[image: XML Retorno]

Comment: O cliente que você está usando do web service é WCF? Como a classe `IIFServiceservice` foi criada (i.e., na mão, usando o "Add Service Reference", etc.)?

Comment: Usando "Add Service Reference".

@carlosfigueira

Comment: Você já tentou usar UTF-8 ? Não tenho problemas usando este encoding.

Comment: @JcSaint não posso mudar o retorno do WebService. Ele já retorna em ISO-8859-1.

Comment: de uma olhada neste post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778384/2588695

Answer (score 2):

Como você está usando o "Add Service Reference", o que o Visual Studio gera para você é um cliente que usa WCF. WCF, by default, usa leitores de XML que são otimizados para certas codificações (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE), e não suporta outros (como ISO-8859-1).

Mas WCF é bem extensível, então você pode trocar o leitor de XML (`XmlReader`) que é usado pelo seu encoder para que ele consiga ler (sem problemas) as outras codificações também. Um dos *samples* do WCF mostra como você fazer isso - ([*Custom Text Encoder*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx), ou [a versão em português](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms751486.aspx), que tem uma tradução automática que não é muito boa).

Só um aviso: se prepare para escrever (ou copiar) um bocado de código. Como eu disse, WCF é bem extensível, mas não é nada conciso. Você terá que trocar o `Binding` usado na sua classe `IIFServiceservice` por um que use um novo `BindingElement`, que cria uma nova classe derivada de `MessageEncoderFactory`, que cria uma nova classe derivada de `MessageEncoder`. O sample tem essas classes para você copiar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma `Web Reference` ao invés de um `Service Reference`:

> Add Service Reference -> Advanced... -> Add Web Reference... -> informe WSDL / URL -> Add Referece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, defina o encoding da requisição:

```
WS client = new WS();
client.RequestEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```